# same dll in multiple project and keeping exes with dll in same folder

Tags: c#, dll, reference

Here I have 'ConsoleApplication01", "ConsoleApplkication02" and I am using COM reference of "Test.dll" in both Applications.
Now I am keeping both Exe's in same location to use functionally. So will it affect its operation due to this.

Comment: i can't say for sure because you don't give much information. but usually it shouldn't

Answer (score 1):

if the dll is the same it will not effect functionality  .
we are using User.dll Kernel.dll almost in all applications .

leave this to OS

Answer (score 0):

Generally, two applications can run together using the same assembly, keep in mind that it also depends on your referenced assembly functionality, for example, if the referenced assembly creates a file with a constant name in working directory and writes to it, the operation will fail if you will try to use this functionality from two applications in the same time.